# App insights settings in azure function app are not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am able to configure app insight directly from app insight tab, by either creating new one or selecting the existing one. In this case, it is updating APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY and APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING in app settings.

But, when I tried to configure app insights through app setting directly, its not working. I have configured APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY and APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING in app settings of a azure function app to directly. But, the related app insight is not integrated with function app.

Can anyone suggest, why it is not working.?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the release notes for [SDK Version 2.0.12998](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12998):

> App Insights configuration will use the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING app setting if it is set (APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY is the fallback and continues to work as-is).

Furthermore, if you read the documentation for [App Insights Connection String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sdk-connection-string?tabs=net), you will notice that when you use connection string, you can specify custom endpoints. This is not possible if you just specify the instrumentation key. In that case, SDK will connect to default endpoints.

Comment: I have gone through the documents, but it still didn't clarify that why the settings are not helpful in integrating app insghts?